# Doubts about onGetDefaultValue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've created a custom preference following the instructions here.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Custom
extending DialogPreference

Everything works but I've some questions I would like to understand.

**First question:**
I've traced all methods and the constructor and I see that the method onGetDefaultValue is called before the constructor call (MyCustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs))
How can it be posible?

**Second question:**
In the example they do

```
@Override
protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
    return a.getInteger(index, DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```

and the say

> The method arguments provide everything you need: the array of
>   attributes and the index position of the android:defaultValue, which
>   you must retrieve. The reason you must implement this method to
>   extract the default value from the attribute is because you must
>   specify a local default value for the attribute in case the value is
>   undefined.

So, must I define the default value at two different places (at the java code and at preferences.xml)? It's a bit extrange I think.

**Third question:**
This is not a question directly related to the onGetDefaultValue method.
How is it that the method
a.getInteger(index, DEFAULT_VALUE);
requires a default value but 
a.getString(index)
doesn't?

Thanks